Strange behaviors of vim omap ge
I found two strange behavior with omap in vim 8.2, vim 9 and nvim 0.10.2. It may apply to all operators (at least d, y, c, which I've tested), but I will pick d as an example below.
Denote end-of-line with ␊.
Case 1
The buffer is
␊
abc␊

The cursor is at b.
With dge, the buffer is cleared except for c, no surprise. However, with d2ge (or 2dge which is equivalent, or d3ge, d4ge, etc.), the cursor moves to the beginning of the first line, and nothing is deleted (or for operator c, we are not left in insert mode)!
Case 2
The buffer is
abc␊

The cursor is at a. With db, nothing changes. This is because b is exclusive. However, with dge, which is inclusive, again nothing changes!
I tried to find in manual, yet with no luck. Can anyone explain such behavior, hopefully with reference to vim's manual? Thank you so much!
Why this is useful to me: I'm developing a vim plugin that extends vim word motions to languages without word boundaries like Chinese. One important feature is to be compatible with vim on ASCII text. Therefore, I need to understand such behavioral details in vim/nvim.

"The cursor is at b. With dge, the buffer is cleared, no surprise." - surprisingly, the c of abc remains in the buffer. Is your example maybe off or did I miss something? Where does :omap even enter the picture? That's what you want to do but it's not in the question, or am I mistaken?

You're right. With dge, c should remain. The wording is not strict enough. I've updated the question. By omap I mean the operator-pending mode usage of the motion ge. I'm not intending to map a key to something else. Sorry for being misleading.

Case 1

dge doesn't "clear the buffer" at all because the motion doesn't include c. Did you mean "The cursor is at c"?
d2ge does nothing because, in your example, it is impossible to move the cursor to the end of the non-existing second previous word. Since there is an error in the motion, the operation is not performed.

Case 2
This is basically the same problem: both b and ge are impossible so the operation is not performed:

If the cursor is already on the first character of a word, b moves the cursor to the first letter of the previous word. No previous word → error → no motion → no operation.
ge moves the cursor to the last character of the previous word. No previous word → error → no motion → no operation.

In other words, the behavior you describe is the expected behavior.

Thank you so much! I kind of understand the semantics of d2ge in case 1, because it seems that d2b exhibits the same behavior if the cursor is on a. So ge is not special. For case 2, notice that dw and de will delete the c when the cursor is on c, but there is no next beginning/end of word either. Should I interpret it as: vim errors out only in backward motion?

e and w are a bit peculiar as Vim tries to be backward compatibility with Vi, which treated them in that weird unintuitive way. As a matter of fact, I actually override them with stricter mappings because I don't like that kind of exception. Case in point, if you enable the bell, you will get it with straight e and w in your scenario but, that's the "weird unintuitive" part I don't like, it won't prevent the operation when used in operator-pending mode. I guess you will have to live with it.
